# How to add the value from a text box to a URl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm using VB.Net and MVC 5.  I have a table that I would like to allow the user to assign a salvage date to an item in.

The table displays multiple fields for the item, and the last field is a textbox like this:

```
<input class="span2" id="salvageDate" name="salvageDate" type="text" 
placeholder=@DateTime.Today />
```

There is a button in the first column of the table like this:

```
@<td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
href="ViewDetails/SalvageConfirmation/@currentItem.Unique_Item_ID" 
type="submit">Salvage</a></td>
```

The item id comes through just fine.

I would like to pass the date to my controller and am not able to.  My controller looks like this:

```
    <Route("ViewDetails/SalvageConfirmation/{itemID:int}/{salvageDate:datetime}")>
    Function SalvageConfirmation(itemID As Integer, salvageDate As Date) As ActionResult
```

I tried using `Html.BeginForm` like this:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("SalvageConfirmation", "ViewDetails", "@currentItem.Unique_Item_ID", FormMethod.Post))
    @<input class="span2" id="salvageDate" name="salvageDate" type="text" 
    placeholder=@DateTime.Today />
End Using
```

but then I end up with a url that looks like this:

> ViewDetails/EditSalvage/14/14/ViewDetails/SalvageConfirmation/14

and if I remove the `href` from the button, nothing happens.

How can I pass the value from the `salvageDate` textbox, that the user selects to my controller?

Comment: Your using the wrong overload of `Html.BeginForm()`. It would need to be `Html.BeginForm("SalvageConfirmation", "ViewDetails", new { itemID = currentItem.Unique_Item_ID }, FormMethod.Post)`. And it appears that this is being used in a loop so remove the `id="salvageDate"` - your generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html

Comment: @StephenMuecke that makes sense(I'm home now and  can't test it).  What do you put in the button to make it follow the `BeginForm` link?  As it is now, the button is trying to follow my `BeginForm` url and the `href` url, so I realize I need to remove the `href`, but when I take it out, there is no action(it doesn't attempt to follow either url).

Comment: It just needs to be a submit button - `<input type="submit" .../>` and be inside the form tags (and the method needs to be a POST (or if its a GET, use `FormMethod.Get`)